# Can’t control servo with Raspberry Pi 5

Tags: pwm, servo, pi-5

I’ve just recently bought my first Raspberry Pi and opted for a Pi 5 as it was the latest.

I’ve had no luck getting gpiozero or gpiod working with Python and my MG996R servos yet.

I don’t mind if it’s not the ‘best’ possible servo control as I’m just experimenting with servos for the first time.

However I can’t find any example python cose That actually allows me to control a
Servo.

All examples for previous raspberry pi versions do not work on the Pi 5

Is something ‘official’ coming out soon or can someone point me at some sample python code that works with Raspberry Pi 5.

I want to start playing with my new toy

Answer (score 0):

Noobie here,

I'm struggling with something similar, I tried to connect a RFID-RC522 module on a pi 5. Apparently, the new chip doesn't support the old RPi.GPIO library. You need to use [GPIOZERO](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for the scripts. Go through it, you might find something that works for you.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try Joan's lgpio which has timed PWM. There are examples https://abyz.me.uk/lg/py_lgpio.html#tx_servo.

This is also the library used by the latest gpiozero V2 (which has examples).